# wcf service method can't trigger

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight project which has WCF servise.When I select treeview's item,WCF service method should trigger but it could not.

## TreeView_SelectedItemChanged

```
 DataProcessServiceClient k = new DataProcessServiceClient();
 k.GetPersonByIdCompleted += k_GetPersonByIdCompleted;
                        k.GetPersonByIdAsync("1");
```

## completed event handler method

```
void k_GetPersonByIdCompleted(object sender, GetPersonByIdCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           secilenPersonel = e.Result as Personel;
           lblHarita.Content = secilenPersonel.tckNo.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: In the treeview_selectedItemChanged, you have subscribed for the event, but you didnt call the k.GetPersonByIDAsync().

Comment: I could not understand.I called  the k.GetPersonByIdAsync("1").